# Dynamically set connectWith while dragging jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, codepen

I have one list that should be connected with another list, but for each item in the list, the target list changes.

I'm using

```
connectWith: '.valid'
```

And then in my `on('sortstart')` function (while the item is being dragged), I'm checking the item properties and appplying the class `valid` to the appropriate lists to connect with. I also then run a `$('.valid').sortable()`

The problem is that even though the class is being applied correctly to the matching list and it even gets the ui-sortable class, the item won't connect with it, but WILL on a second attempt...

I realise this might be asking too much of jquery sortables, but it would really be nice if there is a way.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a simplified codepen more or less showing the problem.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PboBvj

Comment: Your other 2 lists are never initialized as `sortable`. You could not drag an item to them.

Answer (score 2):

First, this may be a possible duplicate of: [reject invalid sortable item in a sortable list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516701/reject-invalid-sortable-item-in-a-sortable-list)

To answer your question, this can be done, just not the way you were driving at. Here is a working example from your example code: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/56kfcba5/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list0" class="source">
  <li id="item-1" data-connect="list1">ITEM 1</li>
  <li id="item-2" data-connect="list2">ITEM 2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list1" class="target"></ul>
<ul id="list2" class="target"></ul>
```

Remember that all IDs should be unique.

**CSS**

```
.source,
.target {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('.source').sortable({
    connectWith: '.target',
    revert: true
  });
  $(".target").sortable({
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      if (ui.item.data("connect") !== $(this).attr("id")) {
        // reject the item
        ui.sender.sortable('cancel');
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Much like the article I linked to, we compare the item from the `source` when the `target` lists receive it. The `connectTo` option can be made to be one-way in this case too. In this way, we have setup targets that will not accept specific items.